# Can I reference a Dockerfile instead of an image in a GitHub Actions workflow?

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, github-actions-services

Checking out the [example-services repository](https://github.com/actions/example-services/), they set up services by referencing to images hosted, like here:

```
    services:
      redis:
        image: redis
        ports:
        - 6379:6379
        options: --entrypoint redis-server
```

We use a custom Dockerfile for Elasticsearch that's stored in the same repository as the workflow, and is not available publicly on Docker Hub. I would like to reference that Dockerfile as the service without having to push and pull from our private registry. Is this possible?

Comment: We don't enable you to reference a Dockerfile here because the services are created before the repository as been checked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to build said image before being able to reference it.
Eg: [Workflow](https://gist.github.com/lavish10/5f870660fb6b4c4ba01bac1ee4a48003#file-workflows-yml-L34)

That means using the "[Build, Tag, Publish Docker](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-tag-publish-docker)", which allows to references a local Dockerfile (meaning part of your repository)

But it also implies to *publish* said image, which might or might not acceptable for your case.